# uninitialized constant GraphqlController::GraphQLSchema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I have Graphiql set up on Ruby on Rails 6.0.3.4, graphql 1.11, and graphiql-rails 1.7.0.

My rails server is running on 0.0.0.0:8080:

```
rails s -b 0 -p 8080
```

Whenever I go to localhost:8080/, I can see  GraphiQL in-browser tool running where I can type graphql queries. According to many tutorials on YouTube, whenever I type:

```
query {
    testField
}
```

In the right pane of GraphiQL, I get:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "uninitialized constant GraphqlController::GraphQLSchema\nDid you mean?  GraphQlSchema",
      "backtrace": [
        "/home/sourav/railsProjects/graphQL/app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:16:in `execute'",
.
.
.
```

The app/config/environments/development.rb file has some added code:

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback = true
config.assets.check_precompiled_asset = false
```

And otherwise, I am just using the default configuration.

I also opened an issue on Github:
https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphiql-rails/issues/86#issue-667943735

For this reason I can never learn GraphQL. What's wrong?

Edit:

I also get this to working if I change the name to GraphQlSchema and then to GraphQLSchema in runtime. It's hard to explain, so I have uploaded a video on YouTube:

[GraphQL Weird Error Ruby on Rails (not something you want to watch)](https://youtu.be/vMGQMiMwTlw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it’s hard to tell for sure, I think the issue is related to the generated GraphQlController using the wrong case for your schema class.

On **line 16** of `/app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb` try making the “L” lowercase like this.

```
GraphQlSchema
```

---

**Update 1:** I'm thinking this is an autoloader problem since the case of "GraphQL" breaks the [default String#camelize used by Rails/Zeitwerk](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#customizing-inflections). I prefer "GraphQL" to be lower cased as "graphql" which requires defining a custom inflection.

Cloning your repository, I was able to get it to reliably work with server and spring restarts with the following changes.

1. I renamed `app/graphql/graph_ql_schema.rb` to `app/graphql/graphql_schema.rb`
2. I created `config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb` with the contents.

```rb
Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    "graphql_schema" => "GraphQLSchema",
  )
end
```

Another solution is to rename the `GraphQLSchema` to satisfy [String#camelize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize). This is not my preferred solution, but it does work.

1. Rename `GraphQLSchema` to `GraphQlSchema` in `app/graphql/graph_ql_schema.rb`.
2. Rename `GraphQLSchema` to `GraphQlSchema` in `app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb`.

The explanation of why this works can demonstrated with IRB.

```
:001 > 'graph_ql_schema'.camelize
 => "GraphQlSchema"
:002 > 'GraphQlSchema'.underscore
 => "graph_ql_schema"
```

Comment: This is very weird error I have ever seen. changing `GraphQLSchema` to `GraphQlSchema` raises another error `"message": "uninitialized constant GraphqlController::GraphQlSchema\nDid you mean?  GraphQLSchema"`, and changing back to GraphQLSchema is working again. Now the weird part is, if I use GraphQlSchema, it raises the error, but if I use GraphQLSchema in runtime, the error goes away, no matter what I use I get the error when I restart the rails server. If you are not sure what I am talking about, please take a look at this video: https://youtu.be/vMGQMiMwTlw

Comment: This is bizarre. Is this a project you can push to github? I’d like to look at it because I’ve not seen anything like this before. I’m wondering if zeitwerk is getting confused with the GraphQL namespace but I’m really not sure.

Comment: I have pushed it to github: https://github.com/Souravgoswami/rails-graphql-test-app

Comment: Thank you! I added an update to show my preferred solution. Basically, I think Rails/Zeitwerk is behaving weirdly with the "graphql" <=> "GraphQL" case transformation.

Comment: "I renamed app/graphql/graph_ql_schema.rb to app/graphql/graphql_schema.org" is that a typo, I think _.org_ should be _.rb_? And yes, with the given steps, the problem goes away, thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh wow, yes it should be `.rb`. I don't know how I typed .org into my edit ‍♂️, but I'm glad you got it working.